# Influence of magnetic dipoles on the atomic structure

Tags: magnetic-fields, atomic-physics

Niels Bohr in 1922:

> „Thus LEWIS, who in several respects independently came to the same conclusions as Kossel, suggested that the number 8 characterizing the first groups of the periodic system might indicate a constitution of the outer atomic groups where the electrons within each group formed a configuration like the corners of a cube…
> It is to be remarked, however, that such a “static” model of electronic configuration will not be possible **if we assume the forces within the atom to be due exclusively to the electric charges of the particles.**“([p.112](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/47464/47464-pdf.pdf))

> “LANGMUIR, who has attempted … to account not only for the occurrence of the first octaves, but also for the longer periods of the periodic system, **supposes therefore the structure of the atoms to be governed by forces whose nature is unknown to us**.“ (p.112-113)

My question now is whether, with the knowledge of the magnetic dipoles of the subatomic particles, we do not have to consider the "unknown" forces announced by Niels Bohr?

Why I’m asking is that Langmuir's shell model - based on Lewis model - with 2, 8, 8, 18, 18, ... electrons per shell follows the empirically established periodic table of the elements. Bohr's shell model according to the formula $2n^2$ with 2, 8, 18, 32, ... electrons is more complicated and the formula is not  comprehensible.

Comment: *more complicated and … not comprehensible* What is more complicated or not comprehensible about $2n^2$?

Comment: @Ghoster Bohr's formula is only comprehensible for the first and second period of the PSE, after that it fails completely, which leads to a lot of exception rules and additional explanations.

Comment: What does PSE mean?

Comment: In the periodic table, the element sequence doesn’t completely fill a shell before starting to fill the next one. For example 4s fills before 3d. See [Madelung rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle#Madelung_energy_ordering_rule). “Electrons fill **sub**shells of the lowest available energy, then they fill **sub**shells of higher energy.” There is more to atomic theory than “fill-a-shell”.

Comment: The Bohr model was replaced by the Schrodinger model almost a century ago.

Comment: @Ghoster Periodic system of Elements

Comment: @Ghoster [Bohr‘s rule $2n^2$ and Schroedingers equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/796389/bohr-s-rule-2n2-and-schroedingers-equation)