# Bohr‘s rule $2n^2$ and Schroedingers equation

Tags: atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

Bohr's model of electron orbitals is outdated.  To what extent has Bohr's rule of atomic structure with $2n^2$ electrons per shell been redescribed? Is the Schroedinger equation based on Bohr's rule of atomic orbital structure with $2n^2$ electrons per shell? If not, do we still adhere to the $2n^2$ rule?

Comment: Look at hydrogen wave functions and see…

Comment: *Is the Schroedinger equation based on Bohr's rule of atomic orbital structure with $2n^2$ electrons per shell?* No, Schroedinger didn’t need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today one determines how electrons fill the shells of atoms by using Pauli's exclusion principle, Hundt's rule and the appropriate set of quantum numbers. The quantum numbers are based on the solution of Schrodinger's equation, which for the Hydrogen atom consists of a radial part and an angular part. The radial part is given in terms of Lageurre polynomials, and are the basis for deriving modern n-shell energy levels; the angular part on the other hand, is given in terms of spherical harmonics and are specified by two additional quantum numbers $l$ and $m$. Further, the electron is recognized to have another quantum number associated with *spin*, thus one needs the set (n,l,m,s) of quantum numbers to completely specify an electron's orbital.

Pauli's exclusion principal is a statement that asserts no two electrons may have the same quantum numbers, i.e. there is a unique (n,l,m,s) for each electron in the atom. Hundt's rule is a principle that claims electrons fill shells in such a way as to minimize the total energy of the atomic system. A consequence of this principle is that some of the outer electron shells may not be filled to completion, i.e. electrons are promoted to a higher orbital despite the one beneath it having room for more electrons.

The chemistry of elements in the periodic table is a consequence of these rules for filling orbitals and thus, one can consult most introductory chemistry texts for details on applying the rules to determine how to fill the shells for any given atom, not to mention that there is usually a table showing the configuration for many elements, if not all of them.

Comment: Albertus, „The radial part is given in terms of Lageurre polynomials, and are the basis for deriving modern n-shell energy levels“ has still its foundation on the number of electrons in each shell n from the equation $2n^2$?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler the rule $2n^2$ determines the theoretical maximum of electrons in a shell, however, the real number differs according to the items in my post.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler This number is determined not from the radial energy levels themselves, but from the consideration of all possible unique $(n,l,m,s)$ for each value of $n$.

Comment: *Hundt's rule* You mean [Hund’s rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules).